# google map API for ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I have been trying to compile the project from http://www.shabdar.org/google-maps-user-control-for-ASP-Net-part1.html but it is complaining

1. The name 'hidEventName' does not exist in the current cont
2. The type or namespace name 'GoogleObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have copied the required files. What am I missing?

Comment: If you give up trying to work with that, I use this one and it works fine. Easy to implement and open source. http://googlemap.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just downloaded the project from the link you specified, opened it in Visual Studio 2010, did the requested conversion, compiled and run it without any problems.

What version of VS are you using?

Comment: The thing is it does not have the sln or csproj files

Comment: @user384080: yes it is developed as a Web Site, not as a Web Project. In order to properly open it, in VS go to File -> Open -> Web Site ... and choose the directory containing the unarchived site. Then select default.aspx as the Start Page (with right click) and run it normally with F5 or Ctrl+F5.

Answer (score 1):

-you delete GoogleMapForASPNet.ascx, and creat new WebUserControl, set name =GoogleMapForASPNet.ascx
you coppy code last GoogleMapForASPNet.ascx into this.
now it's ok

-The type or namespace name 'GoogleObject' -> you not coppy forder app_code
, you coppy two file .cs into project-> ok!

Comment: Just to clear the answer what tuanh is saying: You need to copy the 2 .cs files from the App_code folder to your App_code folder. I had this issue, now it is solved.